# Fusion charts Server side export

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I need to download FusionCharts ExportHandlers for PHP. But I am unable to locate these files and folders in the download zip. Or on the URL http://www.fusioncharts.com

In Download it does not gives any Directory or File related to ExportHandlers.

I need follwoing files:

1. index.php (accepts initial export data and loads format specific export modules)
2. Resources/FCExporter_RLE2IMG.php (Export module to export Flash charts to PNG/JPG)
3. Resources/FCExporter_RLE2PDF.php (Export module to export Flash charts to PDF)
4. Resources/FCExporter_SVG2ALL.php (Export module to export JavaScript charts with the help of Java Batik library)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code in chart object, I have searched for the those resources for my java application but in the newer versions they have removed the files for package.

```
chart:{"exportenabled", "1",  //will enable a icon for download at right top corner
       "exportatclient", "0",
       "exporthandler", "http://107.21.74.91/", //Hits fusionchart server and exports pdf/jpeg/png
       "html5exporthandler", "http://107.21.74.91/"
       }
```

Comment: Not stores images to the specified path, and why did you enable download icon if it works on server side?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will hit the FusionCharts server automatically to export the charts.

```
// Enables an icon for download at right top corner.
chart:{"exportenabled", "1"}
```